# Java interrupted during install

Tags: java, windows, installation, 64-bit

I have been trying to install Java 6 Update 67 (64 bit) on  a computer and I am continuously getting the error that java was interrupted during the install. When I try to delete or uninstall java using tools like javaRA and fixit nothing works. For some reason the computer can install 32 bit java versions, just not the 64 bit versions although it is a 64 bit computer and I checked to make sure of it. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the offline version of JRE.

https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

but its hard to help without more info :-)